# How to do "for each" on output from find?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, find

I would like to find all `mp4` files that is 1920x1080.

If I do

```
find . -type f -name \*.mp4 -exec ffprobe '{}' \; 2>&1
```

it will find all `mp4` files and show the video info. E.g. will the output contain (among other lines)

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './5432223.mp4':
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 1744 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 60k tbn, 59.94 tbc
```

My current ideas are

```
find . -type f -name \*.mp4 -print0|xargs -0 -n1 echo
for f in $(find . -type f -name \*.mp4); do ffprobe $f 2>&1 | grep 1920x1080;done
```

where I can't figure out how to incorporate `if grep -q 1920x1080` and in the first, and in the second white spaces in filenames messes the output up.

**Question**

How do I output only the filename with path if the output matches `1920x1080`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to exec a shell.  Something like:

```
find . -type f -name \*.mp4 -exec sh -c 'ffprobe "$0" 2>&1 |
    grep -q 1920x1080 && echo "$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: For some reason if only works for files without white spaces. I have never seen `sh` being used in `find`. What does that open up for?

Comment: Of course it only works with files without whitespace.  Add double quotes if you need that abhorrent use case!  (answer edited)

Comment: How come you use a new shell?

Comment: The new shell is required to handle the flow control inside the exec'd command.  (If there is a way to do this without a shell, I'm not aware of it.)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
find -type f -name "*.mp4" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
    ffprobe "$file" 2>&1 | grep -q 1920x1080 
    # grep will return zero if the pattern was found:
    if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
        echo "$file"
    fi  
done
```

Comment: If I insert `echo $file` in the for-loop then something very weird going on with the file names. White spaces is a problem and all filename are on the same line it seams.

Comment: With the latest change, then the output is one very long line with all the filenames and still no correctly outputted filenames.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting Yeah I see now.. Seems the IFS doesn't work as (I have) expected. Will find a work around....

Comment: Now it works =) Thanks a lot. The `read -d $'\0'` trick is very cool.

Comment: Thanks! :) Unfortunately I'm currently unsure why my first attempt didn't worked. Will investigate this..