# What is Flow Control in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507677/how-to-do-for-each-on-output-from-find) question the answer was

```
find . -type f -name \*.mp4 -exec sh -c 'ffprobe "$0" 2>&1 |
   grep -q 1920x1080 && echo "$0"' {} \;
```

which will output all mp4 files that are `1920x1080`.

I don't understand why `sh -c` is there. If I remove it, then it doesn't find anything.

The author says

> The new shell is required to handle the flow control inside the exec'd
>   command.

but I guess I am missing some fundamental knowledge to understand the answer.

**Question**

Can anyone explain why `sh -c` have to be there, and why it only works then `ffprobe` is opened in a new shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The -exec option takes a sequence of arguments:

```
find . -exec arg0 arg1 arg2 ... \;
```

If you put the arguments in quotes

```
find . -exec "arg0 arg1 arg2" \;
```

then "arg0 arg1 arg2" are treated as a single argument.  It would expect a command called `arg0 arg1 arg2`, with the spaces, to exist on your system, instead of a command called `arg0` with parameters of `arg1` and `arg2`.

If you were to use find without the `sh -c`, then you would have this:

```
find . -type f -name \*.mp4 -exec 'ffprobe "{}" 2>&1 |
   grep -q 1920x1080 && echo "{}"' \;
```

This would mean that `find` would look for a command called `ffprobe "$0" ....`, passing no arguments -- there is no such command.  There is a command called `ffprobe`, which takes arguments, and that is what you need.  One possibility would be to do something like this:

```
find . -type f -name \*.mp4 -exec ffprobe '$0' 2>&1 |
   grep -q 1920x1080 && echo '{}' \;
```

However, that doesn't work, since the output redirection `2>&1` and the pipe `|` and the command sequence operator `&&` would all be treated differently than what you want.

To get around this, they use another shell.  This is similar to creating a script to do the work:

```
find . -type f -name \*.mp4 -exec myscript {} \;
```

But instead of a separate script, everything is all on one line.

Comment: Part of this is also due to the `exec*` functions in `unistd.h`. In all likelihood (I haven't read GNU find's source) they're using something like execve, and so you're correct in that the first parameter to those functions has to be the binary (executable) to run. That string would be considered one large executable and would cause an error. They mostly (if not all) take either an array of strings or a variable number of arguments for the rest of the arguments passed.

Comment: I am actually very surprised that `$0` gets interpreted as it is inside single quotes. Why does that work?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting: `$0` is getting substituted inside the other shell, which doesn't see the single quotes.

Answer (score 5):

`find` executes the arguments given to `exec` as a command directly (that is it invokes the first argument as an application with the following arguments as arguments to that command) without doing any processing on it other than replacing `{}` with the file name. That is it does not implement any shell features like piping or input redirection. In your case the command contains pipes and input redirections. So you need to run the command through `sh`, so that `sh` handles those.

Answer (score 1):

The difference lies in the implementation of `find`.  Find uses flavors of `fork()` and `exec()` calls of Linux/Unix (Posix) to spawn a new process and pass the command with arguments to it. The `exec()` call runs an executable (binary or shebang interpreted program), passing the arguments directly to it as argument strings.  No processing of those arguments is done.

Therefore shell conventions are not interpreted. E.g. the `$0`, `2>&1` and '|' etc. are passed to `fprobe` as arguments.  Not what you want.  By adding the `sh -c`, you are telling `find` to exec a *shell*, passing the rest of the line to it for interpretation.

Note that you could get the same effect by putting your command in a shebang script and calling this script from `find`.  Here the exec'ed script would load the shell.